# Playing Stream Audio API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I'm currently working with an Audio stream API and am looking to implement a mechanism where I can play the received audio chunks one after another, without waiting for the complete response.

The problem is that I'm encountering jitter issues in the playback. Could anyone provide assistance or guidance on resolving this issue?

```js
const InitialAudio = async() => {
  const response = await fetch(url,)

  if (!response.ok) {
    console.error('Failed to fetch audio')
    return
  }


  const audioContext = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudi oContext)()
  const reader = response.body.getReader()
  let isPlaying = false

  let buffers = []
  let playPromise = null

  const batchSize = 15
  
  async function processChunk({ done, value }) {
    if (done) {
      return
    }
    
    if (value.buffer.byteLength < 1000) 
      reader.read().then(processChunk)
      
    // Create an audio buffer from the chunk
    audioContext.decodeAudioData(value.buffer, function(buffer) {
      if (!buffer) {
        console.error('Error decoding audio data')
        return
      }
      
      buffers.push(buffer)

      // If not already playing, start playback
      if (!isPlaying && buffers.length == batchSize) {
        playNextBuffer()
      }
    })

    // Continue processing the next chunk
    reader.read().then(processChunk)
  }

  // Function to play the next buffer in the array
  function playNextBuffer() {
    if (buffers.length > 0) {
      isPlaying = true
      const buffer = buffers.shift()
      const source = audioContext.createBufferSource()
      source.buffer = buffer
      source.playbackRate.value = 0.93
      console.log({ buffer: buffer.duration })

      const gainNode = audioContext.createGain()
      source.connect(gainNode)
      gainNode.connect(audioContext.destination)

      const crossfadeDuration = 0.01
      const startTime = audioContext.currentTime
      const endTime = startTime + buffer.duration

      let currentTime = audioContext.currentTime + 0.010 || 0;
      
      // Start the source with a fast crossfade
      source.start(startTime)
      gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(0.4, startTime)
      gainNode.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(1, startTime + crossfadeDuration)

      // Schedule the stop with a fast crossfade
      gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(1, endTime - crossfadeDuration)
      gainNode.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(0.4, endTime)
      source.stop(endTime)

      // Resolve the promise after the crossfade duration
      source.addEventListener('ended', () => {
        isPlaying = false
        playNextBuffer() // Play the next buffer when the current one ends
      })
    }

    if (buffers.length === 0 && !isPlaying) {

    }
  }

  reader.read().then(processChunk)
  
  return response
}
```